# Delayed Jobs on Heroku within Sinatra

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

Does anyone have any experience running Delayed jobs on Heroku with Sinatra?

I am creating an image using Rmagick based on user inputs, and would like to take advantage of the delayed jobs on Heroku instead of having the webserver create the images

Has anyone succesfuly pulled this off?  Can you point me to some examples?

Thanks,

Seth.

Comment: Is there anything particularly strange about how one would set this up? Heroku offers a Delayed Job add-on, I think, so after that I'd imagine that it's mostly plug and play. Have you already tried and had troubles?

Answer (score 2):

Heroku co-founder Adam Wiggins has a good example using Sinatra and Clockwork: https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork-sinatra-beanstalk.

Walter

Answer (score 0):

You might probably want to start reading the [Delayed Job Heroku documentation](http://docs.heroku.com/delayed-job).

Comment: I did read that doc, but that specific example deals with a rails app and uses ActiveRecord.  My app uses Sinatra, and does not need to use ActiveRecord.  I was just wondering if there was a simpler solution.

Comment: DelayedJob supports several different backends. See https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/backends